# How do you check if a file is in use?

Tags: livecode

I have a desktop application that writes an XML file out. If the XML file is open in a text editor (from a prior running of the script), when Livecode saves the file out, the XML data is not changed.

The actual line I'm using to write the file:

```
put tOutputData into URL ("file:" & tFilePath)
```

I can see that using "open file-->write-->close file" logic instead of "URL (file:)" will over-write the data if the output file is already open in a text editor. However, the text editor will show the "old" data until the file is reloaded.

How do I ask the file system if the file is already in use before attempting to write to the file in Livecode?

Answer (score 0):

Check the result to see if there was a problem accessing the file:

```
put tOutputData into URL ("file:" & tFilePath)
put the result into rslt
if rslt is not empty then
  beep
  answer error rslt
end if
```